# Adding a time stamp when moving a file in bash

Tags: bash, rename, filenames, variable-substitution

```
#!/bin/bash
while read server <&3; do   #read server names into the while loop    
 if [[ ! $server =~ [^[:space:]] ]] ; then  #empty line exception
    continue
 fi   
echo "Connecting to - $server"
#ssh "$server"  #SSH login
    while read updatedfile <&3 && read oldfile <&4; do     
        echo Comparing $updatedfile with $oldfile
        if diff "$updatedfile" "$oldfile" >/dev/null ; then
            echo The files compared are the same. No changes were made.
        else
            echo The files compared are different.
            # copy the new file and put it in the right location
            # make a back up of the old file and put in right location (time stamp)
            # rm the old file (not the back up)
            #cp -f -v $newfile

                mv $oldfile /home/u0146121/backupfiles/$oldfile_$(date +%F-%T)

        fi 

    done 3</home/u0146121/test/newfiles.txt 4</home/u0146121/test/oldfiles.txt
done 3</home/u0146121/test/servers.txt
```

This is my whole script

```
mv $oldfile /home/u0146121/backupfiles/$_$(date +%F)
```

This moves the file correctly but it removes the actualy file name and just adds the date. I want to keep the original file name and add the current date to the file name.

Comment: What do you mean by "adding a timestamp"? You are renaming the file to the number of seconds since 1 Jan 1970 (that's what `+%s` means to `date`).

Comment: @choroba updated the question

Comment: you can use `mv file /home/u0146121/backupfiles/file_$(date +%F)`

Comment: @RahulPatil that adds the date but doesnt keep the orginal file name as well

Comment: `mv file  /dest/$_$(date +%F)`

Answer (score 6):

Try `mv $oldfile $dest_dir/$oldfile_$(date +%F-%T)`.

`mv $oldfile /home/u0146121/backupfiles/$_$(date +%F)` works in a one-liner if you manually replace `$oldfile` with the name of the file, but if you're specifically referencing the variable `$oldname`, `$` will skip `$oldfile` as an argument and reach back into the history to get the last argument.

Comment: That doesnt work

Comment: Are you using this in a script or as a one-liner? What does it give you as output? What OS are you using?

Comment: no its part of a bigger script. the output is this 2013-07-11-10:22:25
i need to keep the original filename as well

Comment: i will post my whole script for you if you want

Comment: Can you paste the script anywhere?

Comment: i updated the post

Comment: `#!/bin/bash`
`oldfile="test"`
`mv $oldfile ./backup/$oldfile-$(date +%F-%T)`

works as intended for me on Solaris 10. Not sure what else to do - make sure your script is saved before you run it and that you're looking at the right files, but other than that I have no idea.

Comment: I think is just a fundamental error. $oldfile is actually a directory to another file -- /home/u0146121/OldLogFiles/file2.txt

Comment: Sorry to raise an old thread, since it's a dupe, I can't add my own answer. I had to do `mv $oldfile $dest_dir/$oldFile_\`date +%F-%T\`` in my script instead (for some reason, it didn't like the `(`s).